# How to program faster, (generate code from a pattern?)

Tags: ruby, vim

I frequently run into problems that could be solved with automating code writing, but aren't long enough to justify it as tediously entering each piece is faster.

Here is an example:

Putting lists into dictionaries and things like this. Converting A into B.

A

```
hotdog          HD
hamburger       HB
hat             H
```

B

```
def symbolizeType
    case self.type
    when "hotdog"
        return "HD"
    when "hamburger"
        return "HB"
    when "hat"
        return "H"
end
```

Sure I could come up with something to do this automatically, but it would only make sense if the list was 100+ items long. For a list of 10-20 items, is there a better solution than tediously typing? This is a Ruby example, but I typically run into cases like this all the time. Instead of a case statement, maybe it's a dictionary, maybe it's a list, etc.

My current solution is a python template with the streaming input and output already in place, and I just have to write the parsing and output code. This is pretty good, but is there better? I feel like this would be something VIM macro would excel at, but I'm that experienced with VIM. Can VIM do this easily?

Comment: Look at [snipmate](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate), maybe?

Comment: Usually your IDE or texteditor should be able to help you with this.

Comment: @spickermann, do you have an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do this frequently, and I use a single register and a macro, so I'll share.

Simply pick a register, record your keystrokes, and then replay your keystrokes from the register.

This is a long explanation, but the process is extremely simple and intuitive.

Here are the steps that I would take:

### A. The starting text

```
hotdog          HD
hamburger       HB
hat             H
```

### B. Insert the initial, non-repetitive lines preceding the text to transform

```
def symbolizeType
    case self.type
hotdog          HD
hamburger       HB
hat             H
```

### C. Transform the first line, while recording your keystrokes in a macro

This step I'll write out in detailed sub-steps.

1. Place the cursor on the first line to transform ("hotdog") and type <kbd>q</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> to begin recording your keystrokes as a macro into register `a`.
2. Type <kbd>^</kbd> to move the cursor to the start of the line
3. Type like you normally would to transform the line to what you want, which for me comes out looking like the following macro

   `^i^Iwhen "^[ea"^[ldwi^M^Ireturn "^[ea"^[j`

   Where `^I` is <kbd>Tab</kbd>, `^[` is <kbd>Esc</kbd>, and `^M` is <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. After the line is transformed to your liking, move your cursor to the next line that you want to transform. You can see this in the macro above with the final <kbd>j</kbd> at the end.

   This will allow you to automatically repeat the macro while it cycles through each repetitive line.
5. Stop recording the macro by typing <kbd>q</kbd> again.
6. You can then replay the macro from register `a` as many times as you like using a standard vim count prefix, in this case two consecutive times starting from the next line to transform.

   <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>@</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>

This gives the following text

```
def symbolizeType
    case self.type
    when "hotdog"
        return "HD"
    when "hamburger"
        return "HB"
    when "hat"
        return "H"
```

### D. Finally, insert the ending non-repetitive text

```
def symbolizeType
    case self.type
    when "hotdog"
        return "HD"
    when "hamburger"
        return "HB"
    when "hat"
        return "H"
end
```

### Final Comments

This works very quick for any random, repetitive text, and I find it very fluent.

Simply pick a register, record your keystrokes, and then replay your keystrokes from the register.

Comment: This is basically my answer but better

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, there's only a few differences. Aren't macros great!

Comment: I'll mention too, as a vimmer, when I have 100+ lines I've had great success using sed. The string replacement commands are very familiar and it's *super* fast. Yay for old school tools!

Answer (score 4):

For vim, it'd be a macro running over a list of space separated pairs of words, inserting the first 'when "' bit, the long form word 'hotdog', the ending quote, a newline and 'return "', and then the abbreviation and then final quote, then going back to the list and repeating.

Starting with a register `w` of:

```
when "
```

register `r` of:

```
return "
```

an initial list of:

```
hotdog HD
hamburger HB
hat H
```

and a starting file of:

```
def symbolizeType
  case self.type
"newline here"
```

you can use the following macro at the start of the initial list:

```
^"ayeeeb"byeo"wp"apa"^Mrb"j
```

where ^M is a newline.

Comment: That's what I want! Can you explain how to do that in VIM? I know how to record a macro and repeat it, but I don't know how to grab an item and put it somewhere else

Comment: Added a rough example. You just go from one window to the other, for each file. Ask if you'd like some more explanation!

Comment: The `^W`s to switch windows aren't actually in that, I'll revisit this to fix the macro.

Answer (score 2):

For things like this I have a few ways of making it easier. One is to use an editor like Sublime Text that allows you to multi-edit a number of things at once, so you can throw in markup with a few keystrokes and convert that into a Hash like:

```
NAME_TO_CODE = {
  hotdog:          'HD',
  hamburger:       'HB',
  hat:             'H'
}
```

Not really a whole lot changed there. Your function looks like:

```
def symbolize_type(type)
  NAME_TO_CODE[type.to_sym]
end
```

Defining this as a data structure has the bonus of being able to manipulate it:

```
CODE_TO_NAME = NAME_TO_CODE.invert
```

Now you can do this:

```
def unsymbolize_type(symbol)
  CODE_TO_NAME[symbol.to_s]
end
```

You can also get super lazy and just parse it on the fly:

```
NAME_TO_CODE = Hash[%w[
  hotdog          HD
  hamburger       HB
  hat             H
].each_slice(2).to_a]
```

Comment: What is the purpose of converting to a symbol?

Comment: The shorthand notation `{ x: 'y' }` creates a hash with symbol keys. To look anything up in there you need to convert.

Comment: I love the on the fly method. Since runspeed is not an issue, I am using this. Wish I could give a check to both answers.

Answer (score 1):

*snippets* are like the built-in `:abbreviate` on steroids, usually with parameter insertions, mirroring, and multiple stops inside them. One of the first, very famous (and still widely used) Vim plugins is [snipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540) (inspired by the *TextMate* editor); unfortunately, it's not maintained any more; though there is [a fork](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate). A modern alternative (that requires Python though) is [UltiSnips](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2715). There are more, see [this list on the Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Automated_Text_Insertion).

There are three things to evaluate: First, the features of the snippet engine itself, second, the quality and breadth of snippets provided by the author or others; third, how easy it is to add new snippets.